# what are the ways to read and display contents of all .txt files stored in a folder using java?

Tags: java

I need a way to not only read but also display the content of all the .txt files that are stored in a specific folder using java. What are some ways to achieve this?
Let's say that I have a folder **Tasks** which has several text files ***task1, task2, task4,*** etc.
how do I display the contents in these text files using java?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This seems like quite a common task, and I'm sure you researched this at least a little bit before asking here. So please [edit] your question to show your attempts and how they failed and we can work from there.

Comment: I've been researching to resolve this issue for a very long time and the only solutions I have found are about simply listing all the text files, not displaying their contents. I am new to java so I cannot simply copy the code.

Comment: Ok, that's a third of the solution already. Now that you have the file names you can 1) open each file (as you normally would if you had only one file), 2) read that file and print its content.

Comment: I have found a relevant solution to my issue. Thankyou for your time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.